# D3.js scale object without changing its position

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I need to scale a svg object without changing its relative position.
In particular i have a group that contains a rect and a group with some circles, i want to create a transition that change the width and the height of the rect increasing its size by the same scale and scale the group with circles of the same scale factor of the rect but without changing its position.

```
var rect = d3.select("svg").selectAll("rect")
  .transition()
  .duration(750)
  .attr("x", function(d) { return tx(d.x); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return ty(d.y); })
  .attr("width", function(d) { return tx(d.x + d.dx) - tx(d.x); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return ty(d.y + d.dy) - ty(d.y); });

var tree = d3.selectAll("g.tree")
  .transition()
  .duration(750)
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    var sx = (tx(d.x + d.dx) - tx(d.x))/x(d.dx),
    sy = (ty(d.y + d.dy) - ty(d.y))/y(d.dy),
    s;
    if(sx > sy) {
      s = sy;
      rx = (tx(d.x)-x(d.x));
      ry = (ty(d.y)-y(d.y));
    }
    else {
    s = sx;
    rx = (tx(d.x)-x(d.x));
    ry = (ty(d.y)-y(d.y));
    }
    return "scale("+s+")"+"translate("+rx+","+ry+")";});

  d3.event.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: can you add your work in  jsfiddle ?

Comment: Sorry it's not possible because i use some local file in the project; my problem is that when i scale the group it is also translated changing its position respect the rect.

Comment: It sounds like you would need to scale each element individually.